# Efficient random re-ording of vectors

Tags: r, random, vector

The use of a randomization test requires the user to randomly reorder some vector etc as a null model.

In my case I have a vector of 10,000 elements that I must resample from.  Let's make that now:

```
x <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10000, TRUE)
```

So I have real data that looks like `x`.  I want to randomly reorder vector `x`, `n` times.  This can be accomplished:

```
lapply(1:1000, function(i) sample(x))
```

In this case 1000 replications takes:

```
start <- Sys.time()
lapply(1:1000, function(i) sample(x))
Sys.time() - start

Time difference of 10.20258 secs
```

Now consider that some additional computation must take place and this is for one cell in a distance matrix.  Now multiply this overhead by `i` x `j` matrix and it gets time consuming.  **Is there a faster way to reshuffle the `x` vector (preferably in base R) `n` times?**  I use a `list` structure but if a matrix structure is more efficient I'm open to what ever.  In my list the individual elements have the exact same proportion of TRUE/FALSE as the original `x`.  This is key for the randomization test.

Comment: This is because you are printing the output. Try assigning the output of `lapply` to something.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks a bunch.  I didn't realize the printing took that much time.  Can you post as an answer?

Comment: The other obvious option with randomization tests is parallelization. But chopping 9s off a 10s runtime by not printing the answer might be enough :)

Comment: Thanks spaceman, I plan to use parallelization too but want to chop time everywhere I can.

Comment: Just curious, why do you use anonymous function in lapply, if you just call sample on an outside variable?

Comment: @Roman I'm not sure if I follow but what I have done is similar to `replicate` but faster.  Though Sven's answer indicates I'm wrong on this assumption, though [Neal raises some interesting objections](http://radfordneal.wordpress.com/2014/02/02/inaccurate-results-from-microbenchmark/) to microbenchmarking.

Answer (score 4):

Printing in R can be slow (not to mention that not everything always gets printed to the screen).

Try assigning the output instead:

```
> start <- Sys.time()
> out <- lapply(1:1000, function(i) sample(x))
> Sys.time() - start
Time difference of 0.7525001 secs
```

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, `vapply` is faster than `lapply`. You can also consider `replicate` for simple replication since all samplings are independent of `i`:

```
fun1 <- function() lapply(1:1000, function(i) sample(x))
fun2 <- function() vapply(1:1000, function(i) sample(x), FUN.VALUE = x)
fun3 <- function() replicate(1000, sample(x), simplify = FALSE)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun1(), fun2(), fun3())

Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
 fun1() 363.3359 387.9058 531.3358 731.9839  9850.098   100
 fun2() 403.4411 469.3090 587.7403 747.8655 15495.549   100
 fun3() 363.2694 374.1643 516.9334 600.4151  6231.890   100

 # Note that `vapply` returns a matrix, not a list.
```

The function `replicate` seems to be slightly more efficient for this task.